# I want to save my pdf generated in Download folder of the mobile, but I'm not able to save it

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm generating a pdf on button click, and I want to save that pdf in Download folder.

Here's my code:

```
  Directory downloadsDirectory1 = await DownloadsPathProvider.downloadsDirectory;
  final String dir = downloadsDirectory1.path;
  final String path = '$dir/' + fileName + ".pdf";
  final File file = File(path);
  await file.writeAsBytes(pdf.save());
```

And I'm using downloads_path_provider, to get the Download directory. But I'm getting this error.

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/04-Jan-2021 11:31 PM.pdf'

I've even added permissions in AndroidManifest, but still cannot open and save the generated pdf. What could be the issue?

Comment: Are you requested Storage permission? You can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) plugin.

Comment: @fartem, where to request permission?

Comment: Before you starting write to a file. Without permission you don't have a access to a file system.

Comment: Hey @fartem, thank you, requesting permission helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the storage permission worked.